# Route traffic to hosted server from aws vpc

Tags: networking, ip

I am having a DSL Connection in my premises. I don't have any static IP from ISP. My on-premises server is hosted in Italy. Now I want to redirect traffic from my aws vpc instance to my on-premises server. How Can I achieve this? I need expert advise

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this reliably without a static IP on the site that is hosting the services.

Comment: A VPN client doesn't need a static IP address, it can even run through a NAT. And there is nothing technically preventing a VPN server from giving a VPN client a public IP address. Of course such a setup will introduce about twice as many SPoF as hosting directly on the host with a static IP address.

Comment: @kasperd I'm very aware of that. Key word of my answer is "reliably". Having all of the connections break when the IP changes doesn't count as reliable in my book.

Comment: But having the IP address change doesn't have to break any connections in that setup. The clients would not be connected to the dynamic IP address. They would be connected to the static IP address which the VPN server had given to the VPN client. That IP address can remain static even if the IP address which the VPN client uses to connect to the VPN server changes.

Comment: Right, but those connections are tied to an IPSec association with a certain peer. Unless I'm mistaken, all of those TCP connections will need to be re-established if the IP changes, as the kernel will flush all of the states associated with the P1.

Comment: The TCP connections won't be terminated on the dynamic IP address. They would be terminated on the static IP address assigned by the VPN server. The TCP connections might see temporary packet loss while the VPN connection is re-established, but TCP is designed to handle that and the TCP connections won't be broken. TCP will never see any IP address changing. All of this of course requires a VPN solution that can assign a static IP address to a client. There is no guarantee every VPN solution can do this.

Comment: Right, regardless of where the loss occurs, my point about it not being reliable still stands. Can it work? Maybe, for a reasonably low expectation of "reliable".

Comment: Any network link can fail. From the perspective of the TCP connections the VPN connection is just another network link. The VPN connection might be the least reliable network link on the path, but that is not guaranteed to be the case. Should one want to do so, then it is even possible to run two independent VPN connections and use a routing protocol to choose between them like a routing protocol could choose between two physical links.